# Get timespan of every row in datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I doing a small agenda and I will insert the to-do list into a database and populate it in the `DataGridView` along with the `DateTime.Now` when I saved it. If I forget to do something of that list it will display a notification and tell me that I forget to do that.

I want to use a `TimeSpan` of a maximum of  hours and it will only display the notification if it passes the 2 hours long.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
private void GetSpan()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        TimeSpan span = (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value));

        String.Format("{0} hours, {1} minutes, {2} seconds",
            span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
    }
}
```

The problem of this code is that it's only gives me one result and not all of them from each row of the `DataGridView`. So how can I convert it into an array and get each result?

Comment: create a list to hold the formatted strings and add them as you traverse the rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you're on the right track looking to use an array, a `List` would accomplish the same thing and be easier to work with.

```
private List<String> GetSpans()
{
    var timeSpanList = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        TimeSpan span = (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value));

        timeSpanList.Add(String.Format("{0} hours, {1} minutes, {2} seconds",
            span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds));
    }
    return timeSpanList;
}
```

This will give you a whole list of TimeSpans, one for each row in the data grid. Depending on your application, you may want to return a `List<TimeSpan>` instead of a formatted list of strings, but that's up to you.

Alternately, another useful collection type that may help you is `Dictionary`. If you have a unique ID for each row, you could store the results of this function in a Dictionary instead of List; that'd let you quickly look up any given row's TimeSpan by that row's ID later on.

FMI:

- [List Class | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7)
- [Dictionary Class | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7)

Comment: What should it return?

Comment: Heh, sorry, forgot the important part. I added the `return` statement just now.

Comment: To get the results I can do something like it `rchMotivo.Text = GetSpans().ToString();`?

Comment: You could do `rchMotivo.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, GetSpans().ToArray());` (...But if that's all you're looking to do with it, then you could always write the GetSpans() method with `System.Text.StringBuilder` and return one big formatted string instead of `List<string>`.)

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to add the using for [System.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.linq.aspx):

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then you can use this small snippet:

```
IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timeSpans = dataGridView1.Rows.Select(row => (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value));
```

You can use an IEnumerable e.g. in an [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)-loop or convert it to an [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) ([`timespans.ToArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx)) or a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) ([`timespans.ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)).

Your method could look like this:

```
private IEnumerable<TimeSpan> GetSpans()
    => dataGridView1.Rows.Select(row => (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value));
```

Or like this:

```
private IEnumerable<TimeSpan> GetSpans()
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Select(row => (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value));
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
foreach (TimeSpan span in this.GetSpans())
{
    string formattedTimeSpan = String.Format("{0} hours, {1} minutes, {2} seconds",
        span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);

    doSomething(formattedTimeSpan);
}
```

Comment: Even as the author of another answer here, I'm upvoting this one as it'd be most succinct (unless you're stuck using an old version of the .NET framework or something).

Comment: Where I should put `private IEnumerable<TimeSpan> GetSpans()
    => dataGridView1.Rows.Select(row => (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value));`?

Comment: @Rekcs I have edited my answer. It is a simple method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating a list with all timespans, so you can iterate over or select (with linq) all the items you wish to have.

```
// Make returnvalue list of timespans
private List<TimeSpan> GetSpan()
    {
        List<TimeSpan> allSpans = new List<TimeSpan>();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            TimeSpan span = (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[2].Value));

            String.Format("{0} hours, {1} minutes, {2} seconds",
                span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds);
            // Add timespans to list
            allSpans.Add(span);
        }

        // return list
        return allSpans;
    }
```

Now you can iterate through the list in another function by calling

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var time in GetSpan())
        {
            // doSomething with time
        }
    }
```

Comment: It only gives me the result of one row

Comment: Try to add allSpans.count.ToString() somewhere, and see if there really is just one result